# Refreshing UI with a programmatic state

Tags: android, android-activity

I am stumped with a problem. I have an app with a custom button which changes it's drawable based on connection.

I have an option in settings which, when changed needs to re-draw the view and set the drawable based on connection state.

I have implemented onSharedPreferenceChange in my Activity and in there I reload the appropriate UI with setContentView.

After that I set the button drawable based on my connection state. Something like this.

```
String dexterity = prefs.getString(
            getString(R.string.landscape_orientation_key), "Right");
    if (dexterity.equals("Left")) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_left);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
            updateButtonDrawable(myClass.getCurrentButtonDrawable())
```

The UI successfully gets redrawn to it's default state which is without a drawable set as the src of the button. The method I call to update the button drawable has no effect though. Said method is proven and used throughout the app so I am sure that the code works and I have checked that is trying to set the current state.

I thought that it might be that the setContentView hadn't finished when I make the call to updateButtonDrawable. I tried putting the UI update in the onResume() but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show code for `updateButtonDrawable`

Comment: It's a lot of code...But suffice to say it gets the current button state from my service (set correctly in debug) and, based on that it sets the button drawable using button.setImageDrawable

Comment: `setImageDrawable`? What is the kind of `button`?

Comment: ImageButton. As I said, the updateButtonDrawable method is integral to the workings of the app and it called regularly.

Comment: You need to do a `findViewById` inside `updateButtonDrawable` because you have just changed the `contentView` if not you are updating the wrong `imageButton` reference

Comment: That was it man thanks! Answer the question so I can give you a green tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `findViewById` inside `updateButtonDrawable` because you have just changed the `contentView`. If you do not do it, then you are updating the wrong `ImageButton` reference..